# Winsorizing in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

Given a table with an arbitrary number of columns what is the most efficient way to winsorize columns? i.e. set all outliers to a specified percentile of the data? For example, a 90% winsorization would see all data below the 5th percentile set to the 5th percentile, and data above the 95th percentile set to the 95th percentile.

`t:([] a: 100?100; b: 100?100; c: 100?100)`

In the example above I would be looking for code to winsorize columns a and b

I know I can find percentiles like this:
`t: update percentileA: 100 xrank a, percetileB: 100 xrank b  from t;`
but how would I go about substituting the values below the 5th percentile to the 5th percentile, and data above the 95th percentile to the 95th percentile?

Also is it possible to do this in functional form / with a function where I can specify the columns I would like to winsorize and the winsorization percentile (constant across all columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 100 or more rows:

```
ptile:{first x where y=r:100 xrank x};
winsorize:{ptile[x;y]|x&ptile[x;z]};

/update one column
update a:winsorize[a;5;95]from t

/apply to selected columns
@[t;`a`c;winsorize[;5;95]]

/to apply different settings per column
@/[t;`a`c;(winsorize[;5;95];winsorize[;40;60])]
```

A small tweak to the function could generalise it to <100 rows.

EDIT: regarding ignoring nulls in a functional form, you could do

```
ptile:{first x where y=r:100 xrank x:x where not null x};
winsorize:{@[ptile[x;y]|x&ptile[x;z];where null x;:;first 0#x]};

q)(update a:winsorizeOLD[a;5;95] from t where not null a)~@[t;(),`a;winsorize[;5;95]]
1b
```

Comment: Wanted the flag that the function has an unexpected behavior when nulls are present in the columns. Apparently 0n is lower than any other number. Nulls will be changed to the lower percentile which might not be desirable. 

t:([] a: `float$(200?100),-1*(200?100), 0n 0n 0n; b: `float$(200?100),-1*(200?100), 0n 0n 0n; c: `float$(200?100),-1*(200?100), 0n 0n 0n);

t:update aW:winsorize[a;5;95] from t; / unwanted

t: update aW:winsorize[a;5;95] from t where not null a; /solves the issue.

Is there a way to modify the function or 
@[t;`a`c;winsorize[;5;95]] 
to mimic the last code result?

Comment: Edited response above